# What is the importance of inlining in query optimisation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, inlining

I'm reading up on query inlining and I'm finding it very confusing.

On one hand, I'm being told that user-defined scalar-valued functions are terrible for performance because they (almost always) can't be inlined and that this stops the entire query that references them from being run in parallel. Similarly, I'm told that inline table-valued functions are awesome for performance because they can be inlined. On the other hand, I'm being told that I need to worry about repeated work and bad performance from both CTEs and derived tables because they get inlined.

Putting the above together, I'm confused about if inlining is a good thing or not and would like to see an explanation for why it is important for query optimisation. When is it a good thing? When is it a bad thing? How can I spot each of these in execution plans?

Comment: It's two different concepts, just borrowing the words. Inline in function means that the logic gets "embedded" in the query, and there's no need to compile and process every row within a scalar function, which is slow. I'm not sure about inlining in CTEs and Derived tables means. CTE is just a syntax sugar to avoid writing same collection of table joins. But yes, if you repeat CTE twice, then the code gets "inlined" and executed twice as well. Maybe that's what you mean

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you add an example?

Comment: "On the other hand, I'm being told that I need to worry about repeated work and bad performance from both CTEs and derived tables" - being told by who? And under what circumstances? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @DaleK From *T-SQL Querying* (1st edition) "_Note that because SQL Server doesn’t persist the table expression’s result anywhere, whether you use derived tables or CTEs, all references to the table expression’s name will be expanded, and the work will be repeated [..] You can see the work happening twice. A covering index from the Orders
table is scanned twice, and then the rows are sorted, grouped, and aggregated
twice. If the table is large and you want to avoid repeating all this work, you
should consider using a temporary table or a table variable instead._"

Comment: @J.Mini from the sounds of it (hard to know without seeing the query example) that's a situation where you reference the CTE multiple times in the results - which is only one of many CTE use cases.

Comment: But as you can hopefully understand from that description, inlining in that situation causes a negative effect, because the query runs twice, but inlining a function is a positive effect because it allows the query to run in parallel. So 2 very different scenarios.

Comment: To add a bit, i don't actually think disabled parallelism is the biggest drawback to UDFs, but rather the fact that sql server does a row-by-row processing when UDFs are involved, which has a lot of overhead. You can see it if you're running a slow operation with UDF and check the query plan of your query, it will sometimes be in the middle of a UDF text! That's also one of the reasons i think SQL Profiler could tank a server, because all these UDF "visits" made trace even more of a performance sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing three different cases:

a. Inline Table Valued Functions (iTVFs). They are called inline as opposed to multi-statement TVFs. Multi-statement TVFs store query results in temp tables, potentially causing TEMPDB contention. iTVFs do not and they tend to generally perform better (see [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/performance-implications-of-using-multi-statement-tvfs-with/ba-p/305489) interesting article for a performance comparison).

b. CTE inlining. I am not sure, but I think this is relevant to the fact that a CTE is executed every time it is referenced. So, if you join a CTE to itself 3 times, the CTE will be executed 3 times. You are probably better off persisting the results of the CTE to a temp table in this case and reference the temp table in you query, instead.

c. Scalar UDF inlining. Scalar UDFs are notorious for having bad performance, due to a number of reasons, explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16) (Namely: iterative execution, serial execution, lack of costing, interpreted execution). Microsoft tried to improve the situation by introducing scalar UDF inlining, in SQL Server 2019. With scalar UDF inlining, the body of the function is inlined in the query, thus yielding better execution plans. Alas, as you mention in your question, there is a set of requirements that must be fulfilled in order for a scalar UDF to be inlinable. As a result, not all scalar UDFs can be inlined and thus benefit from the performance gain offered by the better execution plan.

Comment: This is very good and probably the correct answer. Can any more be said about why inlining is generally seen as a good thing?

Comment: @J.Mini Thank you. I have more or less shared my knowledge on this subject. In summary, inlining can enable the optimizer to overcome limitations that come with specific object types (TVFs, scalar UDFs) and come up with better execution plans.

Answer (score 3):

The basic thing to understand is that more complex queries are harder to optimize.  The SQL Server query optimizer will spend a limited amount of time searching for an optimal query plan, and the more query operators there are, the more potential query plans the optimizer needs to consider.  So as queries become more complex, the likelihood of finding an optimal plan decreases.

So combining a small number of query operators in a way that allows the query optimizer to find one big plan is a good thing.  But as you add more and more operations to the query, the chances of getting a bad plan increase.

What this means in practice is that you should let the query optimizer do its job, but if you observe that your complex queries aren't getting very good plans, you can make some changes to your query to simplify the query optimization.  One common option is to replace CTEs/subqueries with temp tables, breaking up the query into multiple simpler queries.   Similarly, you can create additional indices, replace views with indexed views or physical tables, add query hints, etc.